# Problem using IBM Watson Assistant for WhatsApp, The word "undefined" appears from nothing using "Type: Options"

Tags: ibm-cloud, whatsapp, twilio-api, watson-assistant, twilio-programmable-chat

[Good morning, The word "undefined" appears from nothing using "Type: Options" on IBM Cloud Watson Assistant for WhatsApp, someone please help me to resolve this issue? thanks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFSQc.png)

Comment: Have you defined a text as title for the list? Have you tried in "try me" to see what it is?

Comment: There is simply no option to edit any possible title.